# Problems with freetype on OSX 10.7.4

Tags: macos, homebrew, freetype, mplayer

I'm trying to install mplayer with OSD using homebrew. I've added both `--enable-menu` and `--with-freetype-config=/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.4.10/freetype-config` to the brew recipe.

```
==> Downloading http://www.mplayerhq.hu/MPlayer/releases/MPlayer-1.1.tar.xz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/mplayer-1.1.tar.xz
xz -dc "/Library/Caches/Homebrew/mplayer-1.1.tar.xz" | /usr/bin/tar xf -
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/mplayer/1.1 --cc=cc --host-cc=cc --disable-cdparanoia --disable-libopenjpeg --enable-menu --disable-x11 --     with-freetype-config=/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.4.10/freetype-config
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/mplayer/1.1 --cc=cc --host-cc=cc --disable-cdparanoia --disable-libopenjpeg --enable-menu --disable-x11 --with     -freetype-config=/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.4.10/freetype-config
Checking for cc version ... clang 4.2.1 (experimental support only)
Checking for working compiler ... yes
Detected operating system: Darwin
Detected host architecture: x86_64
Checking for cross compilation ... no
Checking for host cc ... cc
Checking for CPU vendor ... GenuineIntel (6:15:10)
Checking for CPU type ...  Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T7700  @ 2.40GHz
```

For `freetype-config` I've tried three seperate paths; `/usr/X11R6/bin/freetype-config`, `/usr/X11/bin/freetype-config` and the one in Cellar.

Checking for freetype always fails:

```
Checking for freetype >= 2.0.9 ... no
Checking for fontconfig ... no (FreeType support needed)
```

Although freetype itself seems to be installed.

```
mufasa:bin eythor$ freetype-config --version
15.0.9
mufasa:bin eythor$ freetype-config --ftversion
2.4.10
mufasa:bin eythor$ freetype-config --libs
-L/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.4.10/lib -lfreetype -lz -lbz2
mufasa:bin eythor$ freetype-config --cflags
-I/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.4.10/include/freetype2 -          I/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.4.10/include
```

I noticed that fontconfig depends on freetype so I successfully installed that via brew. I'm not sure what to try next or how to figure out why freetype isn't recognized.

Can anyone point me in a sensible direction?